# How can I make a pivot table with 2 or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have 3 tables, and I want to make a pivot table:

```
CERTIFICATIONS  |  data
-----------------------------------
ID_CERT         |  1  
DESCRIPTION     |  Writer
STATUS          |  A
```

---

```
PERSONAL_CERT    |   DATA
------------------------------------
PNUMBER          |  806
ID_CERT          |  1
LEVEL            |  2
SCORE            |  8.5
```

---

```
PERSONAL  |     DATA
-------------------------------------
PNUMBER   |   806
NAME      |   Ralph
```

---

I need to show a table like this:

```
DESCRIPTION     |     LEVEL 1   |   LEVEL 2   |   LEVEL3   |  LEVEL4
-------
Writer          |    NULL       |   8.5       |  NULL      |  NULL
```

---

I need the table PERSONAL to show the data for a specific employee with "where" and "Like"

Comment: Is it for `mysql` OR `SqlServer` OR `both`?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: it's for SQL server 2008... and I only have the query to join two tables to show description, level and score from the CERTIFICATIONS AND PERSONAL_CERT tables.. I also use the PERSONAL table to show data from a specific person (because I'm doing an employee's broswer)